# Modeling and testing daily arrivals using Nonhomogeneous Poisson Process

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, modeling

How to test first that each days are IID and then it can be model column-wise by nonhomogeneous Poisson process i.e. goodness-of-fit test?

The system from data were collected for $12$ days, runs daily from $8:00am-12:00pm$ i.e. $(0, T]$ Each interval of size $15$ minutes is fixed.

The part of my data is given in the following form

[image]

```
counts={{17,0,0,41,0,0,27,0,22,21,33,0},{28,27,29,0,15,31,20,16,22,12,4,0},{17,21,21,51,27,34,30,18,24,21,26,10},{6,14,12,27,21,18,18,21,26,11,35,32},{23,15,23,27,18,32,21,22,39,12,38,29},{10,12,16,30,12,15,24,20,31,17,29,31},{15,15,9,15,9,23,20,9,34,9,10,22},{8,3,9,14,6,20,10,8,15,8,8,16},{11,10,17,14,10,14,17,14,7,11,21,13},{12,6,8,14,8,12,8,8,9,7,9,18},{8,6,3,9,10,9,6,5,16,8,11,8},{4,5,5,4,6,9,9,3,6,10,8,11},{6,6,4,6,7,8,9,4,10,5,10,9},{10,1,1,3,10,3,6,2,4,5,11,7},{5,3,4,3,3,8,3,2,5,10,6,4},{2,4,2,1,1,3,8,2,6,2,4,4}};

upperlim ={15,30,45,60,75,90,105,120,135,150,165,180,195,210,225,240};
```

Please help me on such either using Mathematica or R.

Thanks for your time.